# How do i draw a sphere, that can scaled to be an ellipsoid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm currently writing a report on the math behind computer graphics. The report is not super advanced, since I'm in high school, but it explores linear algebra, with focus on linear transformations such as rotation and scaling in 3d space (and will write on translation as a linear transformation in 4d vector space using homogenous coordinates). For example purposes I would like to include a figure that shows how a sphere in 3d space can be scaled in the different directions to become an ellipsoid. In the chapter I am writing, I have introduced spheres in the parametric form. I am looking for a way to draw a sphere in latex using the parametric forms and then the same figure, just scaled with *a*, *b* and *c* in the different directions.

(I know this is not a "do this for me" request forum, but I have searched everywhere for something that works, but everything I have tried, doesn't work when I try to translate my figure - I have even asked chatgpt, but none of the responses worked properly)

Here is a reference picture, from another exchange post, for what I'm trying to do.

[image: Example of what I'm looking for]